# Fill pandas row based on iterator matching value in another table

Tags: python, pandas, merge

I need to :

1. iterate over DF1 and for each row
2. match one column value with column value from DF2
3. for each record match, find `code` in another table and assign that code to DF1

> ```
> DF1['CODE'] = 'Nan'
> for index,row in DF1.iterrows():
>     pnum= row['MPBR']
>     for index,row in DF2[['MPBR','CODE']].iterrows():
>         if row['MPBR'] == pnum:
>             DF1['CODE'] = row['CODE']
> ```

This code is working, but it takes eternity. I have 200 000 rows. It's taken 10 minutes for 15 000 rows.

`pd.merge` with `left` or any other combination is not working because it's generating a lot of duplicates which I cannot remove since I'll be removing valid duplicates from various matches which don't have to be unique.

On first match of same MPBR  itterator needs to fetch CODE and update DF1['CODE'] with that value. 
How to speed that up?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've actually extracted unique values of `MBR` in `DF2` with:

```
DF2= DF2.drop_duplicates(subset=['MBR'])
```

and than did left join with `DF1` which ran in second.

```
DF3 = pd.merge(DF1,DF2[['MBR','CODE']],on='MBR', how='left')
```